# How to know the next element in JAXB in Java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a schema something like this

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<!-- Message -->
<xs:element name="Message" type="MessageType"/>
<xs:complexType name="MessageType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Header" type="HeaderType"/>
        <xs:element name="Body" type="BodyType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="HeaderType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="To" type="QualifiedMailAddressType">
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="From" type="QualifiedMailAddressType">
        </xs:element>
</xs:complexType>
<!-- Body -->
<xs:complexType name="BodyType">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>UIH-010-4</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element ref="TEST1"/>
        <xs:element ref="TEST2"/>

    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="TEST1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Gender" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="DateOfBirth" type="DateType" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
    <xs:element name="TEST2">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="salary" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="DateOfDeath" type="DateType" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I have JAXB objects generated for this XML.

My request Message will have either TEST1 or TEST2 inside the body element. What I want to know is that how to know whether it is TEST1 or TEST2.

I know we can read this through xPATH but I am little curious that can we determine through JAXB generated classes

For example if I unmarshall the message

```
MessageType messageType = helper.unmarshal(message);
BodyType bodyType  =    messageType.getBody();
```

Within bodyType it will either TEST1 or TEST2. how do we determine that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
bodyType.getTest1() != null // true if TEST1

bodyType.getTest2() != null // true if TEST2
```

Comment: Its an `xs:choice` which means `TEST1` and `TEST2` likely aren't 2 different properties

Comment: The choice doesn't matter. JAXB will still generate a property for each possible value.

Comment: Gents-- Thank for taking some time out to answer my question but Test1 and Test2 were only two example. What if there are 50 types inside Body in the schema. TEST1, TEST2, TEST3, TEST4..... and only one of them can come. We cannot do null check on all of them and then decide. I need a more cleaner approach.

Comment: I would say you have another question there. This one has been answered.

Comment: James--- I wrote in my question earlier that it was an example. Any one who has coded even a day in Java will know to check for null and move forward.

Comment: So my question is still open -- Is there a cleaner way to do the job?

Comment: I would suggest you edit your original post then as both myself and mks have answered your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

if (null != bodyType.getTEST1()) // TYPE1
if (null != bodyType.getTEST2()) // TYPE2

Comment: Generated the JAXB classes and verified this

Answer (score 0):

XJC generates this class right?

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 @XmlType(name = "BodyType", propOrder = {
        "test1",
        "test2"
 })
 @XmlRootElement
 public class BodyType implements Serializable{

     private final static long serialVersionUID = 12343L;
     @XmlElement(name = "TEST1")
     protected TEST1 test1;
     @XmlElement(name = "TEST2")
     protected TEST2 test2;
```

XML Schema choice element allows only one of the elements contained in the  declaration to be present within the containing element, But for JAXB are two different element.

You haven't way to verify it, Your only solution to use JAXB is a statement like "`if(bodyType.getTest2() != null)`"

Comment: What if there are 50 types inside Body in the schema. TEST1, TEST2, TEST3, TEST4..... and only one of them can come. We cannot do null check on all of them and then decide. I need a more cleaner approach.

Comment: A cleaner solution could be <any> tag.
see this [W3C link](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_any.asp)

XJC generates an attribute "protected Object any"

Comment: The any element enables the author to extend the XML document with elements not specified by the schema. It does not tell you what is the type in your message.

Comment: You should add the attribute "namespace" to restrict it.

Comment: @Guest have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Using your current schema the only way is to use `getTest1() == null` and so on, other awnsers cover that. However if you can change your schema you cant build out a much better design pattern for this expecially if you have many different types.

Take a look at this schema, I created an abstract class called `TESTTYPE` that both `TEST1` and `TEST2` extend and gave that to the `BodyType`

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <!-- Message -->
    <xs:element name="Message" type="MessageType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="MessageType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Header" type="HeaderType"/>
            <xs:element name="Body" type="BodyType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="HeaderType">
        <xs:sequence>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- Body -->
    <xs:complexType name="BodyType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>UIH-010-4</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <!-- ref to the abstract test type complex type -->
                <xs:element name="TESTTYPE" type="TESTTYPE" />
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- base type, really an abstract class -->
    <xs:complexType name="TESTTYPE" abstract="true">
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- TEST1 -->
    <xs:element name="TEST1" type="TEST1"/>
    <xs:complexType name="TEST1">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <!--  java version of class TEST1 extends TESTTYPE -->
            <xs:extension base="TESTTYPE">
                <xs:sequence>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- TEST2 -->
    <xs:element name="TEST2" type="TEST2"/>
    <xs:complexType name="TEST2">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <!--  java version of class TEST2 extends TESTTYPE -->
            <xs:extension base="TESTTYPE">
                <xs:sequence>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

This generates the following `BodyType`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BodyType", propOrder = {
    "testtype"
})
public class BodyType {

    @XmlElement(name = "TESTTYPE")
    protected TESTTYPE testtype;

    public TESTTYPE getTESTTYPE() {
        return testtype;
    }
    public void setTESTTYPE(TESTTYPE value) {
        this.testtype = value;
    }

}
```

and this is `TEST1`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "TEST1")
public class TEST1 extends TESTTYPE
```

and this is `TEST2`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "TEST2")
public class TEST2 extends TESTTYPE
```

---

This allows you to do operations like `bodyType.getTESTTYPE() instanceof TYPE1` or `bodyType.getTESTTYPE().getClass().getSimpleName()`